# Андроид студия склеивает папки. Как убрать?

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем привет. Проблема в том, что студия склеивает пустые папки. Пытаюсь создать нужную иерархию, но она сама их склеивает в одну. Как убрать в настройках, чтобы такого не было?

Пример.
Был стандартный пакет
com.example.exampleapp

добавил вложенные пакет ui и вместо того, чтобы была отдельная папка ui, студия сделала 
com.example.exampleapp.ui

PS хотел скрин вложить, но редактор стака почему то глючит

Comment: Постарайтесь задать свой вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен и людям, которые не сталкивались со "склеиванием" папок. Опишите подробнее какие именно папки,  что делаете, что происходит и тд. Приложите скриншоты. Сейчас ваша проблема более, чем не понятна. Чтобы внести дополнения в вопрос нажмите "править" под вопросом.

Comment: @pavlofff постарался переделать. Спасибо за поправку

Answer (score 8):

Кликните по шестерёнке и снимите галку с пункта `'Flatten Packages'`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если хотите, что бы пакеты вообще папками отображались так, как они есть в файловой системе, то и с пункта `'Hide Empty Middle Packages'`

Comment: аха, столько времени пересоздавал пакеты, даже не думал, что проблема решается в 1 клик!

Comment: @woesss хммм у меня и не было этой галочки. Может он у меня изначально склеил? А как их разъединить, если уже склеились?

Answer (score 0):

*Мне ответ woesss не совсем подошел. Так как у меня уже были "склеины" папки, и галочки данной не было изначально.*

**Мое решение следующее.**
Правая кнопка на любом (нужном) файле -> Refactor -> Move -> и там в папке уже указываем нужный путь и если папка "склеена", то студия их сама разъединит.